# ReactJS добавить пользователю возможность создавать на экране заметку для комментария

Tags: javascript, reactjs

коллеги!

Помогите разобраться с задачей: пользователь приложения создает диаграмму с таблицами, к некоторым таблицам ему необходимо подписать комментарий. Для этого пользователю необходима возможность создать (по клику или обведя область для комментария мышкой) стик (заметку) и расположить ее рядом с таблицей на диаграмме).
Я нашла библиотеку https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-latest-ui/react-sticky-notes но в ней стики слишком яркие и большие. Может, кто-то знает библиотеки похожих компонентов? Я даже не знаю, как еще можно назвать такой компонент: поле комментария? заметка? Подскажите, пожалуйста, а то не знаю даже, что гуглить)